# Call SCP from ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, processbuilder

I uses ProcessBuilder in my app, I need to call SCP ( to upload file ), but I have troble how to give a password . How to  solve this ?

```
String[] commands=new String[]{"bash","-c","scp example.tar.gz username@192.168.0.131 /root/new "};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = pb.start();
```

Where to add password for SCP ?

Answer (score 2):

The [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch) library is better suited for this. Take a look at their [example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch) for scping files.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this would be to use a key pair rather than password authentication. To generate a key pair, login to the remote machine as username. At the prompt type:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

this will generate a ~/.ssh/id_rsa private key and ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub public key. Copy the ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to your local machine, then use the following command lines:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh && touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2 && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2
cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2
```

(note: the mkdir may fail if ~/.ssh already exists - just carry on with the second command in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use an expect script. Create a file containing the following and save it as /some/path/scp_expect. This file should be owned by the user who will execute the Java code.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn scp example.tar.gz username@192.168.0.131 /root/new
expect "assword:"
send -- "password\r"
expect eof
```

Change the password appropriately. Make the file executable:

```
chmod 700 /some/path/scp_expect
```

Now call the expect script from your Java code instead:

```java
String[] commands = new String[]{"bash", "-c", "/some/path/scp_expect"};
```

If it does not work, change `"assword:"` to be a string that is displayed when you are promoted for your password.

Downside of this option is that your password is in the clear in the script, so make sure you consider the security implications of doing this. I'd prefer using the key authentication method myself.